# Variables in my program aren't updating

Tags: vb.net, variables, rename

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop
Language; Vb.net

My program was working fine until I attempted to change the name of the program from 'Windowsformapplication1' to 'ReferencingTool' in the properties tab when you right click the solution in the solution explorer which caused my variables to stop being updated when the code tells them to, this was obviously a problem so I changed the name back but the variables are still not updating.

Example;

```
 If Len(txt_webname.Text) = 0 Then
            lbl_req1.Visible = True And CanContinue = False
        Else
            CanContinue = True
End if
```

The boolean value is set to true by default and the code doesn't change the value, this snippet of code worked perfectly fine before I attempted to change the name of the assembly and root namespace.
If anyone knows how to fix my problem any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: `lbl_req1.Visible = True And CanContinue = False`  this should be 2 statements - `And` wont do what you think it does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
If Len(txt_webname.Text) = 0 Then
    lbl_req1.Visible = True
    CanContinue = False
Else
    CanContinue = True
End if
```

`And` does not connect two statements together. It's a *logical operator*. As used in your original code, it forces the whole line to be evaluated as a single boolean expression, such that the `=` operators in the code are logical `Is Equal To` operations that no longer have anything to do with assignment.

Frankly, I'm amazed the code compiled at all, or at least didn't throw up compiler warnings that should have clued you in.